# Unable to bluetooth pair Galaxy S5 with BG-BluBox

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

I paired a BG-BluBox external sound cube to a Samsumg Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 Edition successfully.

At a later time, I initiated a pairing of the BG-BluBox with a Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0). The pairing was not successful*. I am now unable to pair this device with the S5.

I have located the Bluetooth app under Device Manager and have deleted data and cache and restarted the device.

I have also wiped the cache partition.

In both of the above cases, the outcome is the same. The Bluetooth app on the S5 still shows other paired devices as before, shows the BG-BluBox, but the S5 reports that the PIN/password is incorrect when I try to pair.

How can I pair this device with the S5?

*I may have had to enter a PIN, which I may have entered incorrectly. This was a while ago and I don't recall the details now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33048/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-sabrewolfy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected the S5 to the sound box via the supplied headphone connector jack.

Answer (score 2):

Based on our chat discussion, consolidating

1. By entering PIN correctly on the sound box, you are able to pair with S4 or any other device
2. This doesn't repeat with S5, even after clearing the cache and data of S5 (The first way is to to clear cache and data of Bluetooth app from Settings > Applications Menu > Application Manager.

3.There is no option of resetting memory of sound box and it remembers the last known good connection, which in this case is S4

Available information points to a problem with S5 persisting to remembering the wrong PIN entry and attempting to pair

To fix this,(Considering your device is NOT rooted), would suggest to factory reset your device after taking back up of data and attempt to pair

**EDIT**:  You had mentioned that clearing Bluetooth app data/ cache **did not** clear the saved settings for S4. Which makes me suspect that cache of app is not being cleared. Suggest try this to clear cache of your device -turn your Samsung Galaxy S5 off and press at the same time Power + Home + Volume Down buttons to enter in Recovery Mode. Inside Recovery Mode press “Wipe Cache Partition”  and reboot your phone.  This option I understand had not been tried. You will not lose data. If this also doesn't help, factory reset would be the last resort

Meanwhile, you can mail OEM of sound box to get instructions on resetting or clearing it of stored device information and do that as well to have a clean slate

Comment: My question includes the line, "I have also wiped the cache partition."

Comment: I had seen that but was wanting to make sure that you had done it from recovery.please ignore in that case

Comment: Had the issue been resolved?

Comment: No, it has not.